# Output a string to describe the color and new amount in array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a question about this code that I'm trying to figure out, as I am new to PHP. Here is the code:

```
$fruit_counts=array('apple'=>3, 'banana'=>4, 'orange'=>0);
$fruit_colors=array('apple'=>'red', 'banana'=>'yellow', 'orange'=>'orange', 'plum'=>'purple');
```

How do I output a string describing the color and new amount (count) of each fruit? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Trial and error, and practice.

Comment: And [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: But first decide what you are going to do about colourful fruit that has no count available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it seems like all fruits will have a color, but not necessarily a quantity, just loop through the colors and see if there is a quantity for the corresponding fruit:

```
$fruit_counts = array('apple' => 3, 'banana' => 4, 'orange' => 0);
$fruit_colors = array('apple' => 'red', 'banana' => 'yellow', 'orange' => 'orange', 'plum' => 'purple');

foreach ($fruit_colors as $fruit => $color) {
    $qty = isset($fruit_counts[$fruit]) ? $fruit_counts[$fruit] : 0;
    echo "Fruit: $fruit  |  Color: $color  |  Qty: $qty" . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: @justbaron At least this guy didn't steal my Plums

Comment: Perfect I was focusing too much on the quantity and it was throwing me off but this makes so much more sense now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the fruit counts, with associate colours:

```
$fruit_counts=array('apple'=>3, 'banana'=>4, 'orange'=>0);
$fruit_colors=array('apple'=>'red', 'banana'=>'yellow', 'orange'=>'orange', 'plum'=>'purple');

foreach($fruit_counts as $Fruit=>$Count){
    $Colour = "None!";
    if(isset($fruit_colors[$Fruit])){
        $Colour = $fruit_colors[$Fruit];
    }
    echo "<p>$Fruit ($Colour): $Count</p>";
}
```

OR, if you want all the fruit colours, with associate counts:

```
foreach($fruit_colors as $Fruit=>$Colour){
   $QTY = 0;
   if(isset($fruit_counts[$Fruit])){
       $QTY = $fruit_counts[$Fruit];
   }
   echo "<p>$Fruit ($Colour): $QTY</p>";
}
```

Comment: Ha, Lovely stuff.

Comment: Ah, I see....does the chap want all fruit counts with colours, or all fruit colours with counts...I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ahhh a reformed Fruit Thief. :) Welcome back to polite society.

Answer (score -1):

```
        $fruit_colors=array('apple'=>'red', 'banana'=>'yellow', 'orange'=>'orange', 'plum'=>'purple');
        $fruit_counts=array('apple'=>3, 'banana'=>4, 'orange'=>0);


            foreach($fruit_colors as $key=>$color){
              if($fruit_counts[$key]){
                    echo "Color :".$key." Count: ".$fruit_counts[$key];
              }
            }
```

Comment: _Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of element_

Comment: there is scope to improve the ans of it. at-least you tried to ans the question.